# Самая длинная последовательность повторяющихся чисел C++

Tags: c++, поиск

Вводится последовательность цифр, `0` – конец ввода. Определить самый длинный ряд одинаковых цифр.
Например- пользователь ввел: `10 10 10 10 2 2 3 1 11 11 11 4 4 2 2 0`
Ответ: наибольшая последовательность - `4`, число - `10`
Не используя массивов, списков, коллекций
Как вывести то число которое повторяется ?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int val = 0;
    int current = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int number;
    int counter;

    cout << "enter a natural number (0 if done): ";

    if (cin >> current) {
        counter = 1;

        while (cin >> val) {
            if (val == 0)
                break;
            if (current == val) {
                counter++;
                if (counter > max)
                    max = counter;
                number = val;
            }
            else {
                current = val;
                counter = 1;
            }
        }

    }

    cout << " longest sequence: " << max << " number: " << number << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я вот не понимаю, но почему многие указывают конец ввода? Конец строки определить негзя?

Comment: Конец ввода  и конец строки -- суть разные вещи.

Comment: цифр (в вопросе) или чисел (в заголовке)?

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(counter > max) {
        max = counter;
        number = val;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//  Если писать на языке С++, то может быть такой вариант:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
// компаратор по размеру
struct CmpBySize  {
    bool operator ()(const vector<int>& s1, const vector<int>& s2)
    {
        return s1.size() < s2.size();
    }
};
int main()
{        
    vector<int> v;
    int  k = 0;
    while(cin >> k) {
        if(k == 0) return;
        v.emplace_back(k);
    }
    // очередь с приоритетом векторов типа int  и с  нужным компаратором 
    priority_queue<vector<int>, vector<vector<int> >, CmpBySize> qv;

    auto It = v.begin();
    while (It != v.end()) {
        // диапазон одинаковых элементов
        auto p = std::equal_range(It, v.end(), *It);
        It = p.second;
        //создаем вектор из этих одинаковых элементов
        vector<int> t(p.first, It);
        // добавляем в очередь
        qv.push(t);
    }
    vector<int> res = qv.top(); // первым будет с наибольшим числом элементов
    cout << "max seq:   " << res.size() << endl <<"element:  " << res[0];    
    return 0;
}
```

Или добавить в вашем коде  unordered_map

```
#include <unordered_map>
//...
unordered_map<int, int> m;
cout << "enter a natural number (0 if done): ";
//...
      if(counter > max)
          max = counter;
      number = val;
      m.insert(make_pair(max, number));
     //... 
cout << " longest sequence: " << max <<" number: " << m[max] << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, в своей программе вы на правильном пути, только немного запутались с действиями при смене значения вводимого числа.

Вот работающий вариант (без массивов, векторов и проч.)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
  int nseq = 0, c = 0, p = 0, mxseq = 0, mxv = 0;

  while ((cin >> c) && c) {
    if (c == p) 
      nseq++;
    else { // в соответствии с уже проверенным условием в while() на первой итерации мы попадем сюда и далее все пойдет как по маслу
      if (nseq > mxseq) {
        mxv = p;
        mxseq = nseq;
      }
      nseq = 1;
      p = c;
    }
  }
  if (nseq > mxseq) {
    mxv = p;
    mxseq = nseq;
  }

  cout << "Ответ: наибольшая последовательность - " << mxseq
       << " число - " << mxv
       << '\n';
}
```